# Double loop over one collection in Rust where one loop changes it

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to iterate over the collection `ants` (`Vec<Ant>`). I can't clone the objects.

```rust
for ant1 in &mut self.ants {
  for ant2 in &self.ants {
    if ant1 != ant2 && distance(ant1, ant2) <= Ant::visibility_range() {
      ant1.meet(ant2); // fn meet(&mut self, other: &Self); // - needs.
    }
  }
}
```

The borrow checker hits my hands. How to do that rightly?

Would a solution be to copy needed fields?

Comment: easy answer is close the vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut) to only look at later ants.

```rs
for outer in 1..self.ants.len() {
    let (begin, end) = self.ants.split_at_mut(outer);
    let ant1 = begin.last_mut().unwrap();
    for ant2 in end {
        if ant1 != ant2 && distance(ant1, ant2) <= Ant::visibility_range() {
            ant1.meet(ant2);
            ant2.meet(ant1);
        }
    }
}
```

With this implementation, an ant can't meet itself, but that is impossible anyway due to the signature of `meet`. That is only important if an ant can be inequal to itself, so if you have a sensible `PartialEq` implementation, this doesn't matter.

This implementation also changes the order of meets. `ant1` will meet `ant2` at the same point, but `ant2` will meet `ant1` earlier than in your code. It has the advantage of calculating `distance` half as many times, though.

If you want to keep the order, you can loop over previous and later ants.

```rs
for outer in 1..self.ants.len() {
    let (begin, end) = self.ants.split_at_mut(outer);
    let (ant1, begin) = begin.split_last_mut().unwrap();
    for ant2 in begin.into_iter().chain(end) {
        if ant1 != ant2 && distance(ant1, ant2) <= Ant::visibility_range() {
            ant1.meet(ant2);
        }
    }
}
```

Again, this doesn't compare an ant to itself, but everything else is the same as your code.